# Reading stdin sync in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, stdin

Ok, now I understand that this is "asynchronous" but can I assume that the input of a file passed by cat from a pipe will be in the same order it is read in ( or is it more like an unlocked mess that i can cross my figures will be in the correct order )?

Or is this going to be in order because the pipe is sync and the reads are buffered in order

Am I making any sense here ? Is there a chance a file 1 -> inifinity will be out of order ?

```
var input = ''

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')
process.stdin.on('data',function(chunk){
  input+=chunk
})

process.stdin.on('end',function(){
  run()
})


function run(){
  console.log(input)
}
```

Comment: a) it will be in order, b) why didn't you just TRY?? A handful of lines of code and an immediate answer. Experiments are underrated. How did the guys who gave us the scientific revolution a few hundred years ago do it, with no one to ask :) It will be in order because the OS reads the file in order and puts its contents into the pipe in order. It does not start random threads reading the file from different places on disk, returning the content randomly. It would be the most useless OS file reading routine ever if it returned chunks randomly (without additional info about ordering)...

Comment: Trying this yields the results that I expect but to prove it would require a bit of arcane knowledge .

Comment: That's why I told you. You can infer it yourself though: if you were to get random pieces you would also get position information. On a very low OS level depending on drivers and hardware reading chunks in parallel that are delivered from the piece of storage to the OS unordered *may* be used, but before handing it over to a user level app the OS will make sure it is all sorted. That is how TCP works on the network stack! IP packets and fragments of IP packets can arrive out of order, the OS assembles them in order before handing them to the application they are for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 'synchronous' way of reading the stdin data by using async/await:

```
async function readStdinSync() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let data = ''
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')
    process.stdin.resume()
    const t = setTimeout(() => {
      process.stdin.pause()
      resolve(data)
    }, 1e3)
    process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
      let chunk
      while ((chunk = process.stdin.read())) {
        data += chunk
      }
    }).on('end', () => {
      clearTimeout(t)
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}

async function main() {
  const input = await readStdinSync()
  process.stdout.write(input) // "hello world"
  process.exit(0)
}

main()
```

Note that you have to set a timeout in case there is no stdin data, otherwise it'll hang.

Example usage:

```
$ echo 'hello world' | node stdin.js
hello world
```